# Get value of the pending Promise

Tags: javascript, jquery, html2canvas

I work on create PDF with pdfmake and i get images of many charts with html2canvas.
How i can get the value of the Promise of html2canvas return?

CODE

```
    var img = { token: html2canvas(document.getElementById("chartContainer")).then(canvas => {
    return canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg,1.0")
    }).then(canvas =>{return canvas})}

    console.log (img.token); // Promise { <state>: "pending" }
    alert(img.token); // Object Promise
```

I want to use images outside the function.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: You have two choices: 1. Use a callback in your `then` rather than returning a value 2. Use Async/Await. it appears you want to think of this async operation in a very synchronous way, so I recommend investigating [Async/Await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await).

Comment: The whole point is that you can't get the value while the promise is still pending. Just put the `alert`/`console.log` inside the `then` callback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to wait for the promise to complete. When the promise completes, the function you passed into `.then(/*...*/)` is called.

You also don't need to use an additional `.then` after `toDataURL`, because `toDataURL` runs synchronously (it doesn't return a promise). You only need to use `.then` for functions that return a promise.

So you can rewrite it like this instead:

```
html2canvas(document.getElementById("chartContainer"))
    .then(canvas => {
        // This code will run once the promise has completed
        var img = { token: canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg,1.0") };
        console.log(img.token);
        alert(img.token);
    });
```

Comment: OK, thanks you but i want to use img outside to create my Docdefinition for pdfmake:  var img = null;
    html2canvas(document.getElementById("chartContainer"))
.then(canvas => {
// This code will execute once the promise has completed
img = { token: canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg,1.0") };
});
    
console.log();//null                                                                                    alert(); //null

Comment: You can't "use `img` outside". You can only use `img` where it is **available**, which is **inside** (the then handler). That's fundamental to the entire idea of promises and asynchonicity.

Answer (score 1):

If promises and `.then` are confusing, and you are somehow trying to get values out of the future to use in the here and now, consider `async/await`, which allows you to write asynchronous code in a way which sorta kinda looks synchronous:

```
const canvas = await html2canvas(document.getElementById("chartContainer"));
const token = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg,1.0");
const img = { token };

console.log (img.token);
alert(img.token);
```

Internally, the above code is transpiled or interpreted in such as way as to wait for the `html2canvas` promise to fulfill, using the equivalent of `.then`. In other words, it ends up looking like this:

```
html2canvas(document.getElementById("chartContainer"))
  .then(canvas => {
    const token = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg,1.0");
    const img = { token };

    console.log (img.token);
    alert(img.token);
  });
```

Or, if you don't want to use `async/await` for some reason, you could just write it like this to start with.

PS. Assuming the code above is inside a function, it would need to be an `async function`.